# Google Map Javascript API - How do I add Bootstrap button for modal overlay?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am using Google maps Javascript API.  I want to overlay a Bootstrap button on top of map, which will initiate a modal overlay with helpful hints.

The code below works, but the modal button is not on top of the map.  Help appreciated.

Here's an example in JSBin: [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/arezap/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/themes/base/jquery-ui.css'/>
<link href='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>      <!--Load the Google chart AJAX API-->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>      <!-- Google map API -->
<script src='http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/js/bootstrap.js'></script>


<title>Google Maps</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
  html, body, #map_canvas {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<script>
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<body>

<!-- MODAL OVERLAY START -->
<a data-toggle='modal' href='#myModal' class='btn btn-info pull-left'><i class='icon-white icon-info-sign'></i>&nbspHint</a>
          <div id='myModal' class='modal hide fade' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
          <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'></button>
          <h3 id='myModalLabel'>Welcome</h3>
        </div>

        <div class='modal-body'>
        <h4>Quick Hints</h4>
          <p><small>Blah blah.</small></p>

        </div>
        <div class='modal-footer'>
          <button class='btn' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- MODAL OVERLAY END -->


<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not on the map because the map is just another element on the page, and by default all elements are positioned relatively. You can get around this by extending the bootstrap CSS for btn, upping the z-index, and positioning the element absolutely.

Extend the CSS by adding an extra class to your button. Lets call it "my_mo".

```
.my_mo {
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
}
```

For this to work, the new CSS has to come after the bootstrap CSS (so the positioning setting is overridden).